# UWP app not able to resolve .NET Standard 2.0 assembly

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, serial-port

I have a UWP app and in one of the referenced projects the serial port is getting used. So I made that project a .NET Standard 2.0 project. The UWP app was changed to Target Windows 10 Fall Creators Update (10.0;Build 16299)

As per the [compatibility chart](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/versions.md) it should have worked. But I am getting compilation error

```
Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Type universe cannot resolve assembly: netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51.'
```

I am not sure what is going wrong.

Comment: [This](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2017/09/13/Getting-Started-Xamarin-Forms-with-NET-Standard-20.aspx) may help.

Comment: CoCalceDaw i have installed windows emulator. after installed, i got this issue. Any solution to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 6):

In my case it was an outdated version of the  Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform nuget that was causing this problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try setting not only the *Target* but also the ***Minimum*** version to *Fall Creators Update*.

> When creating a UWP app in Microsoft Visual Studio, you can choose which version to target. Projects using .NET Standard 2.0 must have a **Minimum** Version of Build 16299 or later.
>   [[docs]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version)

Comment: Minimum Version is also set to Build 16299. I have just given up on this. Microsoft has made a royal mess of this whole thing.

Comment: you literally save my day!! I lost hours trying to solve that :|